# Can I upload a PDF to SugarCRM via a Document object?

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, sugarcrm, uploading

I am attempting to figure out how to upload a dynamically generated PDF file to SugarCRM using Java.

At first I thought I would simply need to create a `Document` object and fill in some field expecting a `byte[]` 64Bit encoded as a `String`.  However, from what I've read online, what I'm looking for is not a `Document` but a `Note` with an attachment.  That seems like a poor naming convention in use; am I correct in assuming I need to be creating `Notes`?

In this question I am simply asking for clarification on what a `Document` is, and if it is suited for containing a PDF document or if the only method for uploading a file like a PDF is through `Note`s and their attachments.

(I will ask a followup question elsewhere depending on this question's answer.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use both `Document` and `Note`, but in SugarCRM they are used for two different things.

- Documents: Used for common documents that you want to share with the users and customers (e.g. Letter templates, Product briefs, Terms, etc)
- Notes: Used for documents (or files actually) related to a specific Account, Contact, or similar, which most commonly is for the users only (e.g. Business cases, Emails, Contracts, etc)

You can upload both documents and notes to SugarCRM through the Soap API.

- Documents: Use `set_document_revision`
- Notes: First use `set_entry` with a `Note`, and afterwards `set_note_attachment` to upload and relate the file

*(Disclaimer: I haven't used the "upload documents" in sugarCRM before, but according to the wsdl, it should be possible)*

Comment: set_note_attachment doesn't appear to be in the API I have access to.  I am using Suger version 6.5, does that make a difference?

Comment: I haven't got a 6.5.x installation, but according to the documentation (http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework#SOAP), the method should exist.

Comment: You were totally correct.  I was using some wrapper classes provided by another developer and he did not implement a wrapper for `set_note_attachment`. However, I went ahead and implemented it and it works like a charm.  Thank you again!

Comment: Do you know if these methods work with a custom file module/how do you upload the file via rest for a custom file module?